# Hadoop in Maui+Torque cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, torque

I have a cluster with Torque+Maui. Is it possible to install Hadoop in same cluster? What are pros and cons of doing this if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a good place to start:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hod.html

I haven't worked with it personally but I've heard that this isn't being actively maintained.

From what I've seen Hadoop has its own scheduler which expects a set of Hadoop nodes to be running where the Hadoop file system lives. This is usually a persistent environment so you can load the file system once(big data) and assign your job to a node that happens to hold a copy of the data you need. Torque tends to take any set of free node from the cluster, assigns them to a job, runs the job, then cleans up the environment for the next job. This runs contrary to the design of Hadoop.

I can see where it would be good to have a environment that could do both to fully utilize the systems you already have but management will be messy at best.